# How to get idle time of a window.open() window?

Tags: javascript, html

As soon as the page loads, a window pops open using

```
var pop_window = window.open("third party site url".......)
```

My requirement is to -
1) close the window when the popup window is inactive.

My question - the window can be closed using pop_window.close(). but how to check for inactivity of the window when I only have the handler "pop_window"?

Comment: If it is a different domain, you can not touch that window to know what is going on.

Comment: @epascarello - If I just had to check for mousemove or click over the popup window? still not possible you mean to say?

Comment: You can not touch that window. Same Origin Policy...

Answer (score 0):

You can't you have to have the javascript you need in the new window you open, and if its different domain then you totally can't control or even close,
and even window.close() is not working well for all browsers, it may work for Chrome but not for Firefox, Try it cross browsers before you use in production.

Comment: While doing a window.open("url"...), can't i assign an id to the window?

Comment: No, you can't control it, its security issue

Comment: So there is absolutely no way of checking for inactivity of the window?